# Searching inside an SQL INT field with words

Tags: php, mysql

I have made this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM corso WHERE cat LIKE '%".$_POST["ricerca"]."%' ORDER BY id ASC";
```

I have 2 table (row simulation):

- Corso

  - id
  - nome
- Categoria

  - id
  - nome

In this query i search a value called "Sicurezza" inside `$_POST["ricerca"]` but of course the `cat` contain an id value, like "1" or "2" (database normalization).

Is it possible to associate the searched word such as "Sicurezza" within the "cat" table using the name of the category?

Comment: You can use inner join to the tables

Comment: could you show us an actual data

Comment: `LIKE '%".$_POST["ricerca"]."%' ` is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. See http://bobby-tables.com/ for an explanation, and some examples of how to do this safely in PHP. And as mentioned before, you need to do a join between your two tables, and then you can search any of the fields in the joined tables.